# Show per category metrics in Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am training an object detection model using tensorflow object detection api. The eval config is like this:

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  max_evals: 10
  num_visualizations: 20
  include_metrics_per_category: true
}
```

However, tensorboard doesn't show any per category metrics.
Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: When I set `include_metrics_per_category: true`, I also get the error "ValueError: Category stats do not exist" from [metrics/coco_tools.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py)...

Answer (score 2):

The following steps helped me to display the metrics per category successfully (tested on *faster_rccn* and *mobilenet*):

**1. install updated pycocotools from my git repo:**

> pip install
>   "git+https://github.com/philippschw/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI"

**2. Edit this file in the tensorflow api:**

> "tensorflow/models/research/object_detetcion/metrics/coco_tools.py":from
>   line 240 to line 244

add the following lines of code:

```
# add for metrics per catergory from here
if include_metrics_per_category is True:
    self.summarize_per_category()
# add for metrics per category end here
```

**3.Edit the config file for Tensorflow API to include:**

> {
>       metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics" 
>       include_metrics_per_category: true  }

For example:

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
  num_visualizations: 20
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics" 
  include_metrics_per_category: true   
}
```

Note, an issue for this has already been opened on tensorflow and my solution for now is taken from  [there](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4778#issuecomment-430262110).

Answer (score 1):

Ah I think the pycocotools from github doesn't support this feature. We had this implemented inside of Google, but it's not available outside.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. I remember seeing per category metrics when I used the 'pascal_voc_detection_metrics' in eval_config before the Estimator based training was added?

Comment: I think pascal_voc_detection_metrics still has this but "coco_detection_metrics" might be the only one working with estimator based binary for now. We will add other metrics soon!

Comment: @ZhichaoLu any updates? Would be very good to have this feature!

Comment: It should have been added by this PR(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/5843)

Answer (score 1):

As @zhichau Lu already said, for some reason this feature does not exist outside of google. I was able to get it to work by making the code changes proposed by [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4778#issuecomment-430262110) Github answer.

Here is a pic of my results in Tensorboard:

[image]